# integer wont send over a socket and is received as a String by client

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to create a client/Server chat room program and each client GUI needs to display a list of active users sent from the server. To do this I need to send the number of users in the list for the client. However when I try to sent an int over the socket it throws a type mismatch error. More to the point if I try and send it as a string and then parse it to an int a random alphanumeric string appears out of nowhere. I know the variable I am sending is definitely an integer number though so I don't understand what's going on. I've left in the different solutions as comments too.
Server:

```
   public void updateClientUserList()
        {
            //int userListSize = userList.size();
            output.print((int)userList.size());


            for(int i = 0; i < userList.size(); ++i)
            {
                String user;
                user = userList.get(i).getUsername();
                output.println(user);
            }

            chatLog.add("New user(s) has joined the chatroom");

        }
```

Client:

```
public static void updateUserList()
{
    String users = "";
    //String numInput = input.next();
    int userListSize = input.nextInt();//Integer.parseInt(numInput);

    //for(int i = 0; i < userListSize; ++i)
    //{
    //    String user = input.nextLine();
    //    userList.add(i, user);            
    //}

    //users = userList.get(0);

    for(int i = 0; i < userListSize; ++i)
    {
        users += input.nextLine();
    }

    userListBox.setText(users);

}
```

Comment: Hi, please read how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

To pass an int you need a DataOutputStream ; then u call writeInt like this

```
sockDataOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
sockDataOut.writeInt(11);
```

And in the client side u do:

```
sockDataIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
sockDataIn.readInt();
```